# When to use get/set Methods in java

Tags: java, getter-setter

I want to know when to use get and set methods(getName,setName ) in my class and when simple `classVariable.name = ""` instead `а = classVariable.getName()`

Here is example of class using set and get methods

```
public class ClassExampe {

    String name;
    String course;

    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String studentName)
    {
        name = studentName;           
    }

    public String getCourse ( )
    {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse (String studentCourse)
    {
        course = studentCourse;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If in doubt, use setter/getters, however once you are confident you won't ever need these methods e.g. private inner classes, or package local classes or data value object, you can try dropping them.  They can be fairly easy to add later depending on your project.

Comment: It is better to avoid accessing state altogether if you can... have the client request something be done to the object rather than asking for its state.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the use of 'get'/'set' as part of the method name  is a hold over from JavaBean spec. It is actually unnecessary, as the get or set nature of a method can be seen in its method signature. See Smalltalk for examples of this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Using Getters / Setters vs using Fields

As a rule of thumb:

use the variables directly from the same class (actually from the same .java file, so inner classes are ok too), use Getters / Setters from other classes.

Answer (score 22):

The simple rule is: never use direct access (except, of course, when referring to them from inside the class).

- field access can't be proxied
- you may want to have some event notification
- you may want to guard against race conditions
- expression languages support setters and getters
- theoretically this breaks encapsulation. (If we are pedantic, setter and getter for all fields also breaks encapsulation though)
- you *may* want to perform some extra logic inside the setter or getter, but that is rarely advisable, since consumers expect this to follow the convention - i.e. being a simple getter/setter.
- you can specify only a setter or only a getter, thus achieving read-only, or write-only access.

Even if this does not happen that you need any of these, it is not unlikely. And if you start with field access, it will be harder to change.

Comment: Can I add that using private members and setter/getter also allows read-only or write-only access.

Answer (score 10):

In Java, using a getter and setter is usually considered best practice.

This is because if you ever need to change your code to do something else when a property is accessed or modified, you can just change it in the existing getter or setter.

I tend to think it causes a bit of clutter for simple objects, but if you have ever had to refactor a public property to a getter and setter to add additional functionality you will see that it can be a pain.

Comment: Add to that, your properties should be protected or private. This is information hiding, and you don't want other objects to be able to modify things they shouldn't.

Comment: I would go as far as never anything other than private

Answer (score 8):

I suspect most will say to always use getters/setters to access private members. It's not necessary, but is considered a "best practice".

One advantage is that you can have more than just simple assignment and returning. Example:

```
public void setLevel(int lvl)
{
    if (lvl<0)
    {
        this.level=1;
    }
    else
        this.level = lvl;
}

public int getLevel()
{
    if (this.someIndicator==4)
        return this.level*7.1;
    else
        return level;
}
```

Comment: Almost -1 for using a single letter variable named 'l' (el), which in most fonts looks identical or nearly so to the digit 1 (one).

Answer (score 3):

Getters and Setters allow you to change the implementation later (e.g. do something more complex), allow you to implement validation rules (e.g. `setName` throws an exception if the name is not more than 5 characters, whatever.)

You could also choose to add a getter but not a setter so that the variable is like 'read-only'.

That's the theory, however in many cases (e.g. Hibernate using setters) you cannot throw exceptions in setters so you can't do any validation. Normally the value will just be assigned/returned. In some companies I've worked at, it's been mandatory to write getters and setters for all attributes.

In that case, if you want to access an attribute from outside an object, and you want it to be readable/writable, I just use a public attribute. It's less code, and it means you can write things like `obj.var += 5` which is easier to read than `obj.setVar(obj.getVar() + 5)`.

Comment: I think a better way to handle this special case would be a method for this purpose: `obj.incrVar(5);`

Comment: Yeah, at the end of the day, it comes down to how you feel about the subject. I know what you mean, and I think in some cases its justified, but in many really small objects, people just invest far too much time and code in getters/setters; where a little object with public attributes and the client doing what's necessary would be the correct tradeoff between complexity and safety. But as I said, different people think differently about this topic..

Answer (score 2):

If you mean: when to use public accessor methods instead of making the internal, private variable public my answer is "always" unless there is a severe performance reason.

If you mean, call your own get and set methods vs direct access to the vars w/in your class I still say call your own access methods. This way, any conversion, edits or rules you implement as part of get/set get invoked automatically by your own internal calls as well as external callers.

In pure OO languages (for example, Smalltalk) there is no concept of public - all internal vars are private and so you must use accessors.  In less pure OO languages, you can make things public - however exposing the internals of your data structures and implementation is an exceptionally bad idea for stability and maintenance in the long run. Look up "tight coupling" for more on this.

Simply put, if you expose internal vars publicly, people can access them directly and if you ever change name or type everything down the line breaks.  This is called side effects.

Comment: I would note that downstream breaks causes by changing public interfaces (which is what public variables are) is not a "side effect" - it's a "breaking change".  Side effects are, for example, when you invoke a member method and it has an effect on state outside of the object instance you invoked it on, such as setting a static value in any class.  Or in non-OO languages when it has an effect on anything other than the arguments it was passed.   The C library has many "functions" that cause side-effects - I use the word "function" as used in C, not as in functional programming.

Comment: a stunning nit,(or beer chat)  but I'm not sure I'd agree that public vars are part of the 'interface'. I tend to think of the interface as exposed behavior , not data representation.

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of taste, but generally speaking you always should use get/set methods for all properties that are public. But for things like Value Objects (VOs) that you probably are not going to be bothered with for some time you can use public variables without getting too much criticism I think.

Comment: I would criticize public vars...

Comment: Hehe, of course somebody would :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'd want to use setters and getters to give the opportunity to developers reusing your code by modifying it or extending it to add layers of processing and control when accessing and modifying your internal data. This wouldn't be possible in Java when using direct accesses.

*Parenthesis: However, it's perfectly possible in other languages, for instance in Scala, when the line between properties and methods can become quite fine. And it's great, as then it doesn't become a coding-problem that gets in the way and it makes usage more transparent.*

---

You can also often consider that in your class you can feel free to access your internal (private or protected) members directly, as you're supposed to know what you're doing, and you don't need to incur the overhead of yet another method call.

In practice, multiple people working on a class might not know what everyone's doing and those lines of integrity checking in your getters and setters might be useful in most cases, while the micro-optimization may not.

---

Moreover, there's only one way for you to access a variable directly, whereas you can define as many accessors as you want.

Comment: (Most people just enclose parenthetical thoughts in parentheses instead of annotating a paragraph with the word.)

Comment: I guess I'm a verbose guy, that might be why I don't mind explicit getters and setters. (But that was ridiculous, indeed. See, I'm getting around using it almost right here).

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the private fields of a class and expose them with getter/setter classes the way you want to.